# SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file fail on Linux (part 2)

Tags: c++, linux, openssl

For some reason, my calls to OpenSSL's `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file` have started to fail (again) on Ubuntu. My previous post concerning this function; [SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file fail under Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028862/ssl-ctx-use-privatekey-file-fail-under-linux)

With the above fix, I have been able to use things fine until a couple of days ago. I have no idea why. The error string I'm now getting is `error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib` with `336265225` as error code. What is the problem?

Additional info: The file passed to the function exist (`SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file` is passed the same file). The code in the callback function for the password is also not called (at least apparantly not according to the debugger). Everything works fine on Windows.

Comment: I should add that, for now, this error has gone away. Still, I'd like to know the cause of it in case it happens again.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause: CRLF instead of LF EOLs in the PEM file. It should work on Windows and might not have worked on Linux. Now you upgraded your OpenSSL, maybe the new version can process CRLF on Linux.